# Read raw data from Audio CD

Tags: audio-cd

I would like to read raw bytes from an Audio CD. For other optical formats like UDF or ISO 9660 I simply use:

```
$ cat /dev/cdrom | xxd -a | head
```

But with Audio CD it produces an error:

```
$ cat /dev/cdrom | xxd -a | head
cat: cdrom: Input/output error
```

I tried with various Audio CDs, using `dd`, `cat /dev/cdrom > cd.img` but it didn't work. The idea was to have a sense of the internal structure of the Compact Disc standard.

OS: Ubuntu. But I could use Windows or Mac if there works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure this'll work as I haven't tried it out. I found the solution on [LinuxQuestions forum](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/creating-an-iso-from-an-audio-cd-with-dd-670913/).

Try using this command:

```
cdrdao read-cd -v 2 --device 1,0,0 --read-raw --datafile imagen.bin imagen.toc
```

If that doesn't work, try following the instructions here: [Howto: Duplicate Audio CDs using cdrdao](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/cdrdao)

You'll have to [do it the hard way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/cdrdao#Doing_it_the_hard_way). Only the first step (extracting Audio CD image) is necessary. The second step is for burning the content to a blank CD.

Instructions from the page:

- Install cdrdao

```
sudo apt-get install cdrdao
```

- Find your CD-ROM device

```
  sudo cdrdao scanbus

  Cdrdao version 1.2.3 - (C) Andreas Mueller 
→ /dev/sr0 : Optiarc , DVD RW AD-7590A , 1.52
```

- Create the disk image

```
sudo cdrdao read-cd --source-device /dev/sr0 --driver generic-mmc --paranoia-mode 3 audiocd.toc
```

Answer (score 1):

Another program which can dump raw bytes from a CDROM is `safecopy`. 
http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/

Example of a command to get what you want (equivalent to a .bin file of all data in raw mode, minus the TOC):

```
safecopy -b 2352 -L 2 /dev/cdrom rip.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to create a Wav file for reading raw data for Audio CD? If so, you can get Wav files from Audio-CD by downloading WinDAC or GoldWave or can get Flac files (freerip.com) (recommended).

Comment: No, I want to read raw bytes in the disk, for getting a sense of the internal structure of the Compact Disc standard.